Possible normal forms of a bilinear form
In an old exam, I found the following assignment:
Given an alternating bilinear form $\Phi: \mathbb{Q}^4 \times \mathbb{Q}^4 \to \mathbb{Q}$, what do the three possible normal forms of the coordinate matrix of $\Phi$ look like?
And after that there is also a question about what case applies to a specific bilinear form. But I don't even know what kind of answer the first question might be looking for. What do they mean with the 'normal form' of such a matrix? The lecture was given by some other professor, so maybe they did stuff that I didn't learn about but I would still like to understand.
Answers are appreciated!

As a bit of an analogy as to what the "normal" form might look like: for non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms over $\Bbb R$, signature matrices are the "normal" form for the associated coordinate

In other words, whatever the normal form that they're looking for is, I strongly suspect that they're looking for representatives from each equivalence class under matrix congruence

For an alternating bilinear $\Phi: \Bbb R^4 \times \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R$, assuming we allow for degenerate alternating forms, the coordinate matrix of $\Phi$ must be congruent to one of the following:
$$
\pmatrix{J & 0\0 & J}, \quad \pmatrix{J & 0\0 & 0}, \quad 0.
$$
where $J$ denotes the skew-symmetric matrix
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&-1\1&0}.
$$
The nature of the question seems to imply that the same should be true over $\Bbb Q$.

Very generally, "normal form" means we are studying some collection of objects $S$ up to some equivalence relation $\sim$, and we'd like to choose a "nice" (this is not entirely formal) representative of each equivalence class, which means that every object in $S$ is equivalent to one of our "nice" representatives (maybe up to some permutations). Jordan normal form is a typical example here, where $S$ is the set of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\sim$ is similarity / conjugacy. The "nice" representatives here are matrices chosen to be as close as possible to being diagonal, in some sense.
Bilinear forms can also be represented by $n \times n$ matrices, but now the equivalence relation describing when two such bilinear forms are equivalent up to change of coordinates is not similarity / conjugacy but congruence. Explicitly, an $n \times n$ matrix $X$ over a field $K$ determines a bilinear form on $K^n$ given by $v^T X w$ where $v, w \in K^n$, and if $X, Y$ are two such matrices, the bilinear forms $v^T X w$ and $v^T Y w$ are related by a change of coordinates iff there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that
$$X = PYP^T.$$
This defines congruence.
For example, the classification of symmetric bilinear forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$, or equivalently symmetric $n \times n$ real matrices up to congruence, is given by Sylvester's law of inertia, which can be phrased as asserting that every such matrix is congruent to a diagonal matrix with entries $1, -1, 0$ on the diagonal. So these can be taken to be the normal forms (which are unique if we require the $1, -1, 0$ entries to be in that order).
This question instead concerns the classification of alternating bilinear forms on $\mathbb{Q}^n$, or equivalently skew-symmetric $n \times n$ rational matrices up to congruence. Here I don't know a name for the theorem that produces the classification but it is a slight generalization of a standard result that symplectic forms always have a symplectic basis; Ben gives the explicit answer for $n = 4$ in the comments.
